# SELECT COUNT not using index

Tags: mysql, performance, count, indexing, where-clause

I have a problem with a **select count(*)** because **it is too slow** and I don't know why:

**Table**: tabla_maestra (8 million registers)

**Indexes**: 'codigo_postal' on 'codigo_postal' column, which is a char(5)

**Query**:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM tabla_maestra tm
WHERE (tm.nombre like '%name%' OR tm.empresa_apellido1 like '%enterprise_name%') AND
      (tm.codigo_postal like '08%');
```

This query takes too long (about 4 seconds) because it doesn't use any index. It is to say, this query is doing a full scan (8 million registers). Can anybody explain me why?

I have rewritten this query to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM tabla_maestra tm FORCE INDEX (codigo_postal)
WHERE (tm.nombre like '%javier%' OR tm.empresa_apellido1 like '%javier%') AND
      (tm.codigo_postal like '08%');
```

Now, this query uses the 'codigo_postal' index, but it is **slower: 8 seconds instead of 4!!!**

I don't understand nothing, can anybody help me please?
I would be so grateful. Thanks,
Dani.

Comment: Seeing SHOW CREATE TABLE and EXPLAIN output for both queries wold help ...

Comment: Here are two neat tools to help you get more insight into what mysql is doing: (a) EXPLAIN: Just put "explain extended" in front of each query and run it. MySQL will output what indexes it plans to use and some other helpful info. (b) PROFILING: First, turn on profiling "set profiling=1;" Then run your query. Then "show profiles;" and (assuming your query is the #1 in the list) "show profile for query 1;" Post your results here if you want for more info.

Comment: The "slower" part is probably as the optimizer correctly chose a full table scan right away over first looking up candidate rows by an index scan on `codigo_postal` followed by random row reads of candidate rows found using the index to check the rest of the query condition. Those random access secondary lookups can cost quite a bit.

To improve things you'd need to either have a covering index over all three columns used in WHERE so that the result can be retrieved by an index scan alone, or indexes on each column and optimizer index merge being clever enough to make use of this ...

Comment: Thanks everyone. The problem is that I cannot index in the other columns because the condition is: column like '%pattern%'. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The explain outputs for both queries are:

[image]